# Need help writing a program that bisects a cubic polynomial to find the roots

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that takes inputs from the user to make a cubic polynomial, then taking those inputs and using the bisection method to find the roots. This is for a project at my University and I can only use loops, booleans, if statements, and anything basic like that. The variables "A", "B", "C", "D", "upper_bound", and "lower_bound" were the inputs from the user. They are use to solve for the roots of: `f(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D`. `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are is the range in which the user input and where they know the roots lie within. This is one half of the code that checks if the function is positive and then runs the bisection method.

```py
f_a = A*lower_bound**3 + B*lower_bound**2 + C*lower_bound + D # Plugs the lower bound into the cubic polynomial
f_b = A*upper_bound**3 + B*upper_bound**2 + C*upper_bound + D # Plugs the upper bound into the cubic polynomial
TOL = 10**-6 # The tolerance

upper_bound = new_upper
lower_bound = new_low

if (f_a < 0 and f_b > 0) and ((upper_bound and lower_bound) != 0): # If the equation is increasing from left to right and if the bounds aren't already zeros
    upper_bound = new_upper
    lower_bound = new_low
    while ((abs(new_upper - new_low)) > TOL): # While the area between the bounds is greater than the tolerance, 
        new_mid = int((new_upper - new_low)/2) # Split the bounds into 2, new_mid is the one of the new bounds
        y_mid = A*new_mid**3 + B*new_mid**2 + C*new_mid + D # Finds the y value for the new_mid value
        if ((abs(new_upper - new_low)) < TOL):
            print(new_low, new_upper)

        if y_mid < 0: # If the y value found is negative, perform the next operations
            new_low = new_mid # Replaces the lower bound with the new one, which was found when splitting the bounds

        if y_mid > 0:
            new_upper = new_mid
```

The output is supposed to print every root within the given bounds but I'm stuck in an infinite loop. Everything I change does nothing or makes it loops a number that isn't a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that you are prohibited from using `def` and `lambda`?

Comment: What do you think the statement `((upper_bound and lower_bound) != 0)` achieves, and why is it relevant?

Comment: Why do you have two sets of interval bounds?

Comment: Yea, i'm not allowed to use `def` or `lambda`  and that statement makes sure the inputs for the lower and upper bounds are not already zeros. I've since removed the two sets of interval bounds so there is only one. @LutzL

Comment: Why would that be remarkable if the interval bounds are zero, in contrast to both being one or pi? Does python really allow to apply a logical operation to a pair of floating point numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Removing as indicated in the comments the secondary interval bounds and adding a normalization stage to have the value at the lower bound non-positive results in the code

```py
f_a = A*lower_bound**3 + B*lower_bound**2 + C*lower_bound + D # Plugs the lower bound into the cubic polynomial
f_b = A*upper_bound**3 + B*upper_bound**2 + C*upper_bound + D # Plugs the upper bound into the cubic polynomial
TOL = 10**-6 # The tolerance

if f_a > 0: A,B,C,D, f_a, f_b = -A,-B,-C,-D, -f_a, -f_b

if f_b > 0 and (f_a and f_b)!=0: # If the equation is increasing from left to right crossing zero and if the bounds aren't already zeros
    while abs(upper_bound - lower_bound) > TOL: # While the length of the interval is greater than the tolerance, 
        new_mid = 0.5*(upper_bound + lower_bound) # Split the bounds into 2, new_mid is the one of the new bounds
        y_mid = A*new_mid**3 + B*new_mid**2 + C*new_mid + D # Finds the y value for the new_mid value

        if y_mid < 0: # If the y value found is negative, perform the next operations
            lower_bound = new_mid # Replaces the lower bound with the new one, which was found when splitting the bounds

        if y_mid > 0:
            upper_bound = new_mid
    print( lower_bound, upper_bound )
else: # treat the cases excluded at the start
    if f_b < 0: 
        print( "No sign variation detected in initial interval" )
    else: 
        print( lower_bound if f_a==0 else upper_bound )
```

With the trial values

```
A,B,C,D, lower_bound, upper_bound = 1,-3,4,-7, -10,10
```

gives the result

```
(2.5159800052642822, 2.51598060131073)
```

---

Without the artificial restrictions, this could be done with

```py
def bisection(f,a,b,TOL):
    s = +1 if f(a)<0 else -1;
    if s*f(b) < 0: return "Sign change condition violated"
    while abs(b-a)>TOL:
        c = 0.5*(a+b);
        if s*f(c) < 0:
            a = c;
        else:
            b = c
    return 0.5*(a+b)

print bisection(lambda x: ((A*x+B)*x+C)*x+D, lower_bound, upper_bound, 1e-6)
# >>> 2.51598030329
```